# $W^{⊥} = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n\mid (x, y) = 0 \text{ for all }x \in W \}.$ Which of the following statements are true?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear transformation. If $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, define  $W^\bot = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^n\mid (x, y) = 0  \text{ for all }x \in W \}.$

Which of the following statements are true?

$a. R(A) ⊂ (\ker(A^T))^⊥.$

$b. R(A) = (\ker(A^T))^⊥.$

$c.$ Neither of the above statements need be necessarily true.

My attempt : from rank nullity theorem i found option $b)$ is the correct option

is its true ??

Any hints/solution will aprreciated
thanks u

Comment: oksss @Tortoise..

Answer (score 1):

If $V\subset {\bf R}^m$ is a linear subspace of dimension $k$, then $V^\perp$ is a subspace of dimension $m-k$. It follows that $(V^\perp)^\perp=V$. 
Also we have $$y\in \ker (A^T)\iff A^T y=0\iff (x,A^Ty)=0 \forall x\iff (Ax,y)=0\forall x\iff y\perp R(A)\iff y\in R(A)^\perp.$$

Hence $\ker (A^T)=R(A)^\perp$ and $\ker(A^T)^\perp=R(A)$.

so the  correct answer is  option $a)$ and option $b)$